# Can I use xvfb with AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to offload some code to AWS Lambda that grabs a part of a screenshot of a URL and stores that in S3.  It uses chromium-browser which in turn needs to run in `xvfb` on Ubuntu.  I believe I can just download the Linux 64-bit version of chromium-browser and zip that up with my app.  I'm not sure if I can do that with `xvfb`.  Currently I use `apt-get install xvfb`, but I don't think you can do this in AWS Lambda?

Is there any way to use or install xvfb on AWS Lambda?

Comment: Interesting question.  I'm not sure the answer is 'yes'; while you can include any software you like in the package, as you allude, I'm not sure you'll be able to get an X environment to run.  But, then again, why not?  It's just sofware after all, and all the hardware would be emulated in your case.

Comment: @Chad did you make progress on this?

Comment: @Fo Unfortunately no.  I ended up checking out some 3rd party services that create screenshots, but we needed it to be as fast as possible and be able to find the coordinates of a CSS selector and crop the screenshot to that.  So we just setup another EC2 server with xvfb and chromium.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `Xvfb` on aws lambda with a bit configuration. For a working example see https://github.com/nisaacson/aws-lambda-xvfb

To get this to work, you need `Xvfb` and `xkbcomp` compiled with some special configuration values. Then you will need to bundle some shared libraries with your lambda function...

---

Compile xorg-server with the following flags to get the `Xvfb` binary

```
./configure
    --with-xkb-path=/var/task/xkb \
    --with-xkb-output=/tmp \
    --with-xkb-bin-directory=/var/task/bin
```

Compile `xkbcomp` with the following flags

```
./configure \
    --prefix=/usr \
    --with-xkb-config-root=/var/task/xkb
```

Compile `xkeyboard-config` with the following flags

```
./configure \
  --prefix=/usr \
  --with-xkb-base=/var/task/xkb
```

Comment: I tried your approach in a recent docker image, things work in general, but only if I yum install the mesa drivers (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/60083999/4556546). Did things work out for you without doing anything about the drivers?

Comment: @ikkjo - do you have any update here? seems like a lot of stuff in the dockerfile is outdated

Comment: @fullStackChris, no I don't, sorry. I gave up on this a the time.

Answer (score 0):

No, this breaks the lambda paradigm of having a fully built container ready to go.

Also, anything you'd do with xvfb is probably going to be slow.  As a general rule lambdas should execute in under a second, otherwise you should just have a server.

I would recommend creating a docker container and making an auto-scaling group.

Comment: I think you're fundamentally correct, yet it seems like it's theoretically possible, remembering the [Lambda limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) of deployment package size of 50 MB compressed, 250 MB uncompressed, which might rule this out right away... *everything* has to be in the zip file, which does in effect create the "fully-built container."  You'd need to zip everything needed to run in the [Lambda environent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) and for it to be usable in place without ordinary "installation."

Comment: You can pull up to 500MB into /tmp in your Lambda instance as well

Comment: [This guy](https://gist.github.com/cpsubrian/3aa40f6f3d6ce2c707b9d8e34c652dcf) is tantalizingly close to a solution